# Compiling from server leads to unresolved problems no matter how much I try. (MPI connections...)

Tags: makefile, server, mpi

Sorry for bothering you with this. I usually don't ask questions where I can't provide much info but I'm getting anxious over this because I've been trying for days to make something run.

So, I'll try to be as straightforward as possible.

1. Everything I try on the server, I have first successfully compiled/run it (not to the max cuz of computational time) on my Desktop PC.
2. I have no root access on the server (can't use any sudo commands)
3. The main problem is when I try to `make` a problem and execute it. (Problem with make OR problem with MPI connection to peer)

The code I'm replicating with make is a code-named "BHAC code" and I have managed to run some problems on the server but some others not (when changing some things that are listed as options on the code and have tested them on my pc).

The main problems can be summarized into 2 main points:

- `undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5'` even though when I try `make -lpthread` it still shows the same error
- after successfully compiling some problems (that don't show the 1st problem) and I try to run them, some of them don't even start showing:  `MPI_ABORT was invoked on rank 0 in communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD with errorcode 128.` -`NOTE: invoking MPI_ABORT causes Open MPI to kill all MPI processes. You may or may not see output from other processes, depending on exactly when Open MPI kills them.` 
  This is the best summary I can do.

I know it's basically not much and therefore ANY advice (even how to begin to solve it, like what to copy from my pc to the server somehow) would be helpful.

Really thanks and sorry for the question

EDIT 1:

I access the Cluster through 'ssh' command. From there, the enviroment is "slurm" and using `SBATCH` commands to send jobs.

Before I send a Job there, I first try it on my Desktop computer. So Im transfering those files. `make clean` and `make` so I can run. On some problems I have the following (1st) error:

```
mod_odeint.o  mod_oneblock.o mod_lu.o mod_rtsafe2D.o mod_interpolate.o mod_ngmres.o mod_random.o  -o /scratch/astro/mpisketzis/flatbeam/bhac
/home/astro/mpisketzis/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: watchdog.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/home/astro/mpisketzis/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /home/astro/mpisketzis/anaconda3/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/../sysroot/lib/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [bhac] Error 1
```

(I still dont know why it doesnt identify the libraries with -lpthread)

On some others that do successfully `make`  I get this unreasonable error:

```
  Local host: node45-005
  Local PID:  233819
  Peer host:  node45-004
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[node45-005][[50621,1],67][btl_tcp.c:559:mca_btl_tcp_recv_blocking] recv(19) failed: Connection reset by peer (104)
[node45-005][[50621,1],67][btl_tcp.c:559:mca_btl_tcp_recv_blocking] recv(27) failed: Connection reset by peer (104)
[node45-005][[50621,1],67][btl_tcp.c:559:mca_btl_tcp_recv_blocking] recv(28) failed: Connection reset by peer (104)
```

Comment: make sure `-lpthread` is put at the **end** of the link command. If you are using `GNU` compilers, you can also try the `-pthread` flag. The second error message suggests the application did call `MPI_Abort()`, so this is something you can debug on your own since you have the source code.

Comment: You can't run `make -lpthread` that doesn't make any sense.  There's not much to go on here.  You haven't even explained what you mean by "on the server".  Are you trying to copy files back and forth between your local system and some other remote system?  You should only copy source code between systems.  Recompile the source from scratch, don't copy object files/libraries/etc.  Beyond that we really can't help without some actual specific questions, or at least details about what you're doing.  For example, if you have a link error show us the link command line.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet What do you mean, at the end of the link command? I mean I didnt put it on start. Also I dont think its on Source Code because I actally run the exact same run on my Desktop

Comment: @MadScientist  I'm sorry not very experienced. What do you mean Command Line / Link Error? I didnt want to post the exact errors cuz I thought it would be too much. I edited my Question so I think you can see more specifics now.

Comment: try `make V=1` or `make -n`, it should display the link command line. Then you can check the position of `-lpthread`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet What I mean is that i put -lpthread on the `make` command. not on the `makefile`. I dont think it changes anything, no?

Comment: It does change everything!

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Wait really? And how do I put it on the `makefile`?

Comment: With your preferred editor!

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I meant. how exactly do I add it. Do I just write `LIBS = -lpthread` ?

Comment: read my previous comments, manually link your app with `-lpthread` and see if it helps.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I'm Sorry. I checked the previous comments but didn't really got where I should put `-lpthread`  with `make -n` there come a WHOLE list with `entering directory / leaving director` cycles and no clue on where to put it

Comment: run `make V=1` in the directory where your app is linked

Comment: `make` is an execution orchestrator for small batches of shell commands. By itself, `make` doesn't have the faintest idea what linking is, so giving it `-lpthread` on its own command line doesn't do anything, or rather `GNUmake` seems to ignore `-lpthread` because it is an invalid form of the `--load-average` switch and you fell victim to this on your desktop machine. You need to locate your linker command inside the makefile and amend it with a reference to pthreads. Also see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Libraries_002fSearch.html#Libraries_002fSearch